# python: encapsulate data without a class?

Tags: python, oop, encapsulation

I have a module in python that provides various functions for performing database queries. 
It looks like this:

```
def do_some_query(conn):
    ## logic goes here

def do_something_else(conn):
    ## logic goes here
```

Where `conn` is a database connection object. Of course, this means a lot of passing around of the `conn` object. 
I'd like to allow the user to just set the connection object once for their session and then call the functions.

OBVIOUSLY putting the whole thing in a class is a good answer, but I dont want to have to make the user initialise a class each time they want to use the functions. 
I.E, I dont want the API to be like this:

```
 from database_module import DatabaseClass

 db = DatabaseClass()
 db.connect(...)
 db.do_some_query()
```

But like this:

```
 import database_module as dm

 dm.connect(...)
 dm.do_some_query()
```

Is there a way to either 'hide' the class from a user, or provide encapsulation without the class?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `connect` function that puts the connection in a global variable, and the other functions will use it.

```
_conn = None

def connect():
    global _conn
    _conn = ...

def query():
    _conn.execute("SELECT ...")
```